# UV unwrap: separate maps for separate faces problem

Tags: mesh, uv

The problem is:
I have 1 mesh.
I want some faces of the mesh to be in one map (faces A) and other faces of the mesh in another map (faces B).
Now when I unwrap faces A, there is no problem, I get a UV map only with these faces.
When I unwrap faces B to a new UV map, there is faces B and faces A on that map. While on the first map there is only faces A.

Is there a possibility to only get faces B on the second map or can I just move the faces A away?

EDIT:
[image]

In the file there is a plane. I first picked some vertices and unwrapped them with U -> Unwrap leading to UVmap1.
Afterwards I picked some other vertices, created a new UV map with the + and then unwrapped them. Now if you select all and switch between the maps you will see that UV map 1 contains only the first vertices and uv map 2 contains the first and the second ones.

Comment: Jonathan, perhaps you might be so kind as to upload a copy of your Blend file to [Blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), or a similar site. Please do not use Pasteall, or other sites which arbitrarily delete your file after some length of time. You can have multiple UV maps on the same object, but seeing your blend file would help those wishing to help to explain the process more clearly.

Comment: @brasshat, well I didnt think that it was necessary, because it is a fairly simple issue. but sure, no problem, I'll upload a file, so you can visualize it better :)

Comment: Jonathan, the simplest questions sometimes have the most complex answers, furthermore, what the questioner thinks is a simple question is sometimes not simple at all, it only seems simple to the questioner because he or she hasn't the background to understand all of the implictions of the question.

Comment: @brasshat I definitely understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have separate textures for separate faces.

One technique is to scale the vertices of unwanted faces by zero to the median point. Scale 0.  The area of the faces are now zero. Zero area signals no mapping is attempted.  I hope the single dot on the uv map is acceptable to you.

[image]

- mark seams so as to partition faces into group A and group B

First UV Slot

- uv unwrap case 1 and move unwanted faces to the side of uv map. The texture repeat must be set to [clip].

Second UV slot

- uv unwrap case 2 and move unwanted faces to the side of uv map. The texture repeat must be set to [clip].
- The combination of faces of the uv map and repeat set to [clip] should achieve your goal

Keep in mind advanced users may be able to simply use one uv map with texture painting.  You are the advanced user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I knew all this and I wanted to know if there is a way not to "move the unwanted faces aside" but rather to not have them on the UV map at all. I dont know about the texture repeat though and how to set it on clip maybe you could explain this? Oh yeah and I dont want to just use one uvmap because there are faces which exist twice in different layouts, I will use a slighty transparent texture on top of a non-transparent one.

Comment: When I look at the original post I see one sentence with a [?].  I selected that as the question which I attempted to address.  Please consider changing your original post with a new question.  See the note above please.

Comment: yes, I know you responded to my question about texture set to clip. Btw I just try now to put the islands I dont need off the picture and scaling them down f.e. Thank you! :)

Comment: Successful or Not Succesful?