# How to paint a texture on, based on the way it was mapped on with UV?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I UV Projected an objec[image]t, but now I want to paint certain parts of that map onto it without the whole thing. How can I do this so that the parts I paint still look like the same parts of the map?

EDIT

All the settings you need to see are in this screenshot :-)

Comment: In the proposed answer below is a screen image.  Please show your screen image so as to reveal some of your Blender Texture Paint settings.  Show your uv map as well.   Update your question rather than put pieces of the question in comments where the the pieces are difficult to assemble.

Comment: But then how will it be the size I want?

Comment: I think you should focus on the big feature first and save the minutiae for last.  If your work is a learning experiment with texture painting a cube that is great.  The time investment seems small.  I would delete the file and start again from zero to eliminate previous small problems.   Please rework your UV Map. Delete all maps and start fresh. In this simple example I believe the uv map should fit within the UV square area, not sticking out on the sides. I think you should have one simply finished uv map. It is only a cube correct? Lets keep the topic to texture painting and uv map only.

Comment: I meant if you scale everything down to fit, how will it ever look right.

Comment: Images can get scaled up and down, sometimes with undesirable scaling artifacts.  For a simple cube I expect a simple uv map.  Of course seams are possible. Are you trying to paint a texture on a limited number of faces and leave the other faces with no paint texture?  That question has been answered at this site at least once by others and myself.  I am not sure I understand the question.  Because the cube image is black and the uv map looks overly complicated I suggest you delete the file and redo with a reasonable uv map.  Please also show the vertices of the cube in edit mode.

Comment: Part or all of your question may be similar to  ..........http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35954/uv-unwrap-separate-maps-for-separate-faces-problem/35958#35958

Comment: It's different than that.

Comment: I think i will let this discussion rest for a while and let others contribute.  Thanks for the dicussion. It was a worthwhile review of the texture painting features.  Here is a worthwhile tutorial ...... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tovu1A0LxeQ

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In texture paint mode you can either

- Paint and modify the existing texture image such as (.png) file.
- Paint on a new texture and layer the textures so that one covers the others.
- Paint with a brush from one image to another final image ... rather like a clone tool from GIMP

A video tutorial for texture painting is probably a necessary resource for ease of explanation and understanding.

Comment: But i start painting with the uv map I modified selected and it repeats everywhere. this is because the way I modified it my uv faces are overlapping. How can I just paint parts of it so some parts reveal the map I made in the uv editor?

Comment: 2 separate images are used.  The brush is a texture image as depicted above.  The final image is the recipient of the brush strokes.

Comment: I don't understand. What did I do wrong and how should I go about fixing it?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot