# How to texture paint a mesh while it's transparent?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

So I finished modelling my mesh for a spaceship and moved on to texture painting it. The problem is that I'm following the design of an image in the background and I cannot see it while painting as the mesh is black. Is there some way to make it transparent so I can see the image while painting or...?
[image: My model in Texture Paint Mode]

[image: The image I am following]

Comment: Thats good question. I'm not sure if you can do that, but what you could do is take that background image into something like photoshop or gimp and paint onto that and adjust it to how you want, then just apply that texture to the model, otherwise you might have to simply paint it with the bg image as a reference...

Answer (score 1):

If it's just about seeing a reference image, which you loaded in as a Background image to a view, you can set the display of it to 'Front'. It's the Button under the 'Opacity' slider, by default it is set to 'Back':

[image: set display to front]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Texture Paint with Brush Mapping Stencil**.

In texture paint mode open the texture panel, select stencil, and select a destination image.  Slot creation may take care of some of these steps.

Texture Paint allows the user to paint directly on the surface, flat or not.  The paint source is shown below on the left, the human figure with transparent background.  The destination image is on the right with UV Map edges.  The transparent, of some level, brush stencil is in the middle with the yellow arrow.  You may choose the level of transparency.  The leg portion was painted. Position was changed. Head portion painted.  The pixels were copied from the Stencil image.

The sphere shape has a UV Unwrap which appears in the UV Image Editor window.

Remember to save the destination image. Counterexample. I had to paint twice because I forget to save. Thus image below is different than the one above. Strive to paint on surfaces directly facing view. Avoid painting faces in silhouette.  Counter example.  The smudge below is when I painted the faces in silhouette.

[image]
Image above.  Render result and the target image.

For the final render in Blender Render the target image was specified as a texture.  Cycles also applies textures in a different easy manner.  That detail is a separate question.

Know that the slot interface in the texture paint allows you to choose diffuse color slot and create a new blank image for the destination image.  I encourage you to try this on examples first which can be discarded then your production work.

Please see this answer as well.

[How to paint a texture on, based on the way it was mapped on with UV?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38190/how-to-paint-a-texture-on-based-on-the-way-it-was-mapped-on-with-uv/38191#38191)

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to Blender and don't really understand how to do that. is the stencil transparent by default?

Comment: Do you see the texture panel on my image on the left portion .... and the Blender texture paint window on your computer?  Open that texture panel and select your image.  Part of the approach is to get you progressing  in the correct direction and let you discover somethings.  As indicated above,  I can not do justice to the texture painting in a short answer the way a video tutorial would.  There are so many features.

Answer (score 0):

Go to PropertiesEditor->Object->Display->Wire

This will let you see the wireframe of your mesh in texture paint mode.

Now all you need to do is change the color of your ship to anything but black.